# Limiting API Access

Tags: node.js, api

I'm trying to create an API in Node.js, but I was wondering how I can limit access to the API to just a certain frontend website. I don't want others to be able to access the API unless its through my frontend site.

Answer (score 0):

Configure CORS and restrict to your specific domains. And add in an Authorization token if you can.

Comment: Does this apply to React applications that communicate with the API via axios?

Comment: My setup is specifically with VUE using axios to call an AWS hosted API. In AWS CORS was configured so that the API could only be called from my production domain.